# Why does my strcmp fail?

Tags: c++, sql, oracle, oracle11g, string-comparison

I am working on an application, where if this certain error message is given, it is ignored:

> [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-24338: statement handle not executed

My code for comparison is the following:

```
char Sqlstate[10];
long NativeErrorPtr;
char MessageText[1024];
long BufferLength=1024;
long TextLengthPtr;

SQLGetDiagRec(SQL_HANDLE_STMT,sqlc.g_hstmt,1,(SQLCHAR *) Sqlstate,(SQLINTEGER *) &NativeErrorPtr, 
(SQLCHAR *) MessageText,(SQLSMALLINT) BufferLength,(SQLSMALLINT *) &TextLengthPtr);

success=false;          
char* msg = MessageText;
char* oracleMsg = "[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-24338: statement handle not executed";

int i = strcmp(msg, oracleMsg);
```

I am getting `i ==1`.   When I hover over both `msg` and `oracleMsg` they look exactly the same. Here is the copied text from each variable.

> oracleMsg 0x00c1cd88 "[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-24338: statement handle not executed"    char *
>
> msg   0x0132d0a4 "[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-24338: statement handle not executed"    char *

Comment: maybe the error message in not NULL-terminated. `msg[TextLengthPtr] = 0;`.

Comment: When I try to add that code, I get the unhandled exception 'Access violation writing location 0xcd81cf88'.

Comment: try to use strncmp instead

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code which declares and initializes the variables used in the call to SQLGetDiagRec, especially MessageText, BufferLength, and TextLengthPtr. Thanks.

Comment: Alright. I have edited the post to include the variable's initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem must have been that it is not NULL-terminated.  I followed ibre5041's advice and used `if((strncmp(msg, oracleMsg, 55))== 0)`.  This only compares the first 55 characters, which avoids the non NULL-terminated issue.